# Zip and Unzip within Memorystream

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream

I'm trying to save some files in a String.

The files are zipped, the zip-file read as ByteArray, and the ByteArray is converted into a String using `Convert.ToBase64String`.

When I used to Create an actual Zip-File it worked, but now I'm trying to do it in MemoryStream and I get:

> FileFormatException: "File contains corrupted data."

Here's a Function I've been using to diagnose the problem:

```
Private Sub PushToBase64StringStream(tSourceDirPath As String)
    Dim byteArray() As Byte

    Using cStream As New MemoryStream
        ZipManagedFilesStream(cStream, tSourceDirPath)

        cStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        byteArray = New Byte(CType(cStream.Length, Integer)) {}
        cStream.Read(byteArray, 0, CInt(cStream.Length))
        'Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)

        ' This statement works
        Using cPackage As Package = Package.Open(cStream, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    End Using

    Using cStream2 As New MemoryStream
        cStream2.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        cStream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)

        ' This statement fails
        Using cPackage As Package = Package.Open(cStream2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

In the first Using-Statement I call the Unzip-Function using the original stream and it works. In the second Using-Statement I call the Unzip-Function using a new Stream which is filled with the original byteArray and it fails, claiming the File is corrupted.

```
Private Sub ZipManagedFilesStream(cStream As Stream, tSourceDirectory As String)
    Using cPackage As Package = Package.Open(cStream, FileMode.Create)
        For Each cFile As FileInfo In ManagedFiles(tSourceDirectory)

            Dim tType As String = Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip
            Dim cPartUri As New Uri("/" & cFile.Name, UriKind.Relative)
            Dim cPackagePart As PackagePart = cPackage.CreatePart(cPartUri, tType, CompressionOption.Normal)

            Using cSourceStream As New FileStream(cFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                  cTargetStream As Stream = cPackagePart.GetStream
                cSourceStream.CopyTo(cTargetStream)
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Apologies, if someone tried to dig into this - I found the Problem myself. It lies within this Line:

```
byteArray = New Byte(CType(cStream.Length, Integer)) {}
```

The ByteArray is too long by 1 Byte. I've changed it to:

```
byteArray = New Byte(CType(cStream.Length - 1, Integer)) {}
```

Now it works.

---

**Edit:** Its a lot easier to do this:

```
Using cStream As New MemoryStream
    ZipManagedFilesStream(cStream, tSourceDirPath)
    Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(cStream.ToArray)
End Using
```